# android back4app. how to rollback or when is the commit point (transaction control)

Tags: android, transactions, commit, rollback, back4app

I'm working on a project with **CometChat API** and **back4app for DB**.
I have a question on **user signing up level**.

I was told to use other DB than CometChat's itself for maintaining User info.
Working on it, I faced a problem with transaction control.

**My app goes like this** (registering user info)
1. back4app insert
2. cometchat insert

Here, I was wondering **what if 1st goes right and 2nd goes wrong**. I definitely need to **rollback** 1st insert too.

If back4app commit point is somehow controlled, I just need to know when it is and how to control it.
If not, please tell me what should I do with above.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let me see... Would you like to rollback the cloud code?

If so, in this case, you can use the CLI (Command Line Interface) for that. After the setup, you only need to run the `b4a rollback` command. Then, it will return to the old cloud code version.

Click on the link below to know more about the CLI:

https://www.back4app.com/docs/platform/command-line-interface

Comment: Thank you. I've just done it by deleting the first result.